# Eliminar filas que contengan valores mayores que las filas anteriores

Tags: r

Tengo un masivo fichero csv que responde a la siguiente estructura minimizada:

[Datos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcwxhns109ewat8/data.csv?dl=0)

Aquí la tabla de datos insertada:

```
Ronda   Tratamiento
5        A
6        A
7        A
6        A
7        A
3        B
4        B
5        B
6        B
7        B
6        C
7        C
6        C
7        C
5        C
6        C
7        C
6        B
7        B
```

La columna ronda contiene valores ordenados desde un valor arbitrario hasta 7.
Me gustaría eliminar de la columna ronda todas las filas que contengan un valor numérico para ronda mayor que el valor numérico de la fila anterior. O en otras palabras, conservar solamente las filas que contengan el primer valor en que la serie creciente hasta 7 se inicia.

Por ejemplo, en el ejemplo aportado, obtener algo así:

```
Ronda   Tratamiento
5        A
6        A
3        B
6        C
6        C
5        C
6        B
```

Estaba intentando crear una columna adicional con la idea de después borrar filas. Pero no estoy familiarizado con estas operaciones en R. Seguro que existe un método mucho más efectivo y directo. Copio, en cualquier caso los esfuerzos:

```
v <- c()
data$Round <- as.numeric(data$Round)
for (i in seq(1:(nrow(t)))) {
  v <-c(v, ifelse(t[i+1,5]> t[i,5], 1,0))
}
t$keep <- v
t<- t[!(t$keep==0),]
```

Gracias por la ayuda,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pensamos el problema de otra forma podríamos decir que lo que buscas es obtener las filas dónde cada `Tratamiento` tenga el valor mínimo de `Ronda` para ese `Tratamiento`.

Partiremos de estos datos:

```
df <- data.frame(Ronda=c(5,6,7,5,6,7,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,6,7,6,6),
                 Tratamiento=c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B',
                               'C','C','C','C','C','C'))
```

Esto, usando R base puede resolverse de la siguiente forma:

1. Obtenemos los valores mínimos de `Ronda` por cada `Tratamiento` usando `aggregate()` y la función `min()`:

   ```
   minimos <- aggregate(Ronda ~ Tratamiento, df, min)

   minimos
     Tratamiento Ronda
   1           A     5
   2           B     3
   3           C     6
   ```
2. Teniendo los valores mínimos de cada grupo vamos ahora a filtrar las filas del `data.frame` principal, hay varias formas, la que se me ocurre bien sencilla es usar `merge()` para hacer algo que en SQL se conoce como  `INNER JOIN` es decir la intersección de los dos conjuntos de datos:

   ```
   merge(df,minimos,by = c("Ronda","Tratamiento"))
     Ronda Tratamiento
   1     3           B
   2     5           A
   3     5           A
   4     6           C
   5     6           C
   6     6           C
   ```

Puedes, y es muy recomendable, usar `dplyr` dónde las operaciones anteriores son mucho más legibles:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(Tratamiento) %>%    # Agrupamos por Tratamiento
    filter(Ronda == min(Ronda))  # Solo filas dónde Ronda sea el mínimo del grupo
```

#### Edición:

Según lo último que mencionas, necesitas la primer fila del primer valor de la serie ascendente, en este caso creo que con R base es más simple por que es un poco de aritmética de vectores:

```
df[c(max(df[,1]),df[1:nrow(df)-1,1]) - df[,1] > 0,]

   Ronda Tratamiento
1      5           A
4      6           A
6      3           B
11     6           C
13     6           C
15     5           C
18     6           B
```

Detalle:

- Con `c(max(df[,1]),df[1:nrow(df)-1,1])` generamos un vector con las `Ronda` pero desfazado un elemento y con el valor máximo como primero:

  ```
  [1] 7 5 6 7 6 7 3 4 5 6 7 6 7 6 7 5 6 7 6
  ```
- Si lo restamos al vector original `df[,1]`, es decir:

  ```
  [1] 5 6 7 6 7 3 4 5 6 7 6 7 6 7 5 6 7 6 7
  ```

  Obtendremos algo así:

  ```
  [1]  2 -1 -1  1 -1  4 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  2
  [16] -1 -1  1 -1
  ```

  Si prestamos atención, los valores positivos son justamente los primeros de cada serie ascendente, por lo que utilizaremos esto para "filtrar" las filas finales convirtiendo este vector en uno lógico: `c(max(df[,1]),df[1:nrow(df)-1,1]) - df[,1] > 0` que usaremos para filtrar las filas que nos interesan.

Comment: muchas gracias por la repuesta. Me he dado cuenta de que el archivo de datos que subí originalmente no era representativo del archivo de datos original. Resulta (Ley de Murphy) que existen valores mínimos de Ronda que difieren dentro del mismo Tratamiento, pues responden a varios tests. Por eso estaba intentando una aproximación diferente. He actualizado los datos para ver si me puedes echar una mano. Muchas gracias, como siempre.

Comment: @pyring, los datos del enlace parecen ser los mismos. Saludos.

Comment: he cambiado algunas filas y ahora también he insertado la tabla de datos en la edición para facilitar la lectura. En la tabla de datos actual, existen varios valores mínimos para cada Tratamiento, uno por cada serie creciente de Ronda terminada en 7. Por ejemplo, para el Tratamiento A, en sentido creciente de fila, la primera serie de valores de Ronda es (5, 6, 7). Aquí queremos conservar solo la fila con el 5. La segunda serie de valores de Ronda es (6, 7). Aquí deseamos conservar solo la fila con el valor 6. Y así sucesivamente. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @pyring, entendí, revisa mi edición por si te sirve. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Saludos.